# Retrieve email ID instead of name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

Below coding retrieves all the information from `.msg` files. However, when it retrieve the email ID of sender and received, it is reflecting name instead of email ID. Please assist me and advise as to what changes are required to display the email ID instead of name.

```
Dim MyOutlook As Outlook.Application

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim x As Namespace
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Path As String
Set MyOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set x = MyOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Path = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\My working\Macro\New folder\Ilearn - Grp 1\"

FileList = GetFileList(Path + "*.msg")
Row = 1

While Row <= UBound(FileList)

    Set Msg = x.OpenSharedItem(Path + FileList(Row))

    Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 1) = Msg.Subject
    Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 2) = Msg.Sender
    Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 3) = Msg.CC
    Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 4) = Msg.To
    Sheet2.Cells(Row + 1, 5) = Msg.SentOn
    Row = Row + 1
Wend
```

Comment: No @Dave , post formatting issues...

Comment: Depends on your version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710191/getting-messageid-from-email-in-outlook-vba-2003